# How to reduce notification duration time?

Tags: questdb

When running a query via the Web Console, a notification appears.

However, I feel that it lasts too much time, and it impedes my view and performing other tasks.

How do I configure the amount of time after which notifications in the Web Console must automatically disappear?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is not a user-configurable feature, but the project is open to requested changes via [GitHub issues](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues)